# Query: SUM, AVG 3 days of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, average

Here's my sqlFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6ed6a/3

I have a food log that holds a food item, total calories, date, and grams of protein, fat and carbohydrate.

I'm trying to calculate the percent of carbs, protein and fat consumed each day for 3 consecutive days for each user.

I'm retrieving the data with this query:

```
SELECT foodName, calories, carbs, fat, protein, logDate
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN FoodLog
ON Students.id=FoodLog.studentID  
WHERE FoodLog.studentID  != ''
AND logDate >= '2019-02-03' AND logDate <= '2019-02-05'
ORDER BY `FoodLog`.`logDate`  ASC
```

However, when I try retrieving the data with a percent, I only get one food item returned as in the following query:

```
SELECT foodName, calories, carbs, fat, protein, logDate,
((SUM(carbs)*4)/SUM(calories))*100 AS percentCarbs
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN FoodLog
ON Students.id=FoodLog.studentID  
WHERE FoodLog.studentID  != ''
AND logDate >= '2019-02-03' AND logDate <= '2019-02-05'
ORDER BY `FoodLog`.`logDate`  ASC
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: You forgot to add `Group By` on `foodName`. It will give you foodwise distribution of data.

Comment: Thank you!! :) That solved the issue of only one result being returned. Now it's showing all days, but the percent of carbs is showing for each food item and not for each day. Should I just do that with PHP code or is there a better way with my query?

Comment: So `GROUP BY students.studentID, logDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are just missing group by

```
SELECT foodName, calories, carbs, fat, protein, logDate,
((SUM(carbs)*4)/SUM(calories))*100 AS percentCarbs
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN FoodLog
ON Students.id=FoodLog.studentID  
WHERE FoodLog.studentID  != ''
AND logDate >= '2019-02-03' AND logDate <= '2019-02-05'
GROUP BY FoodLog.studentID, logDate
ORDER BY `FoodLog`.`logDate`  ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run that query, I get percentCarbs for each food item instead of percent carbs for each day.  

Here's a fiddle showing that - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6ed6a/6  The result I'm trying to get to would be as follows using 2/3/2019 as an example. 

Since total grams of carbs for that day is 35+43=78*4=312 (4 calories per gram). Total calories for that day is 170+254=424. 312/424 would be 73.5% carbs consumed for 2/3/2019.  

I'm not sure how to edit the query to do that or if it's easier/better to run those calculations using PHP?

Comment: try removing group by foodname. if that doesn't work then I'm not sure I understand your problem

Comment: This isn't a LEFT JOIN, as would be evidenced by executing EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS